# implementing hikaricp with microsoft sql server

Tags: java, hikaricp

I am trying to figure out the best approach for using hikaricp (JDBC connection pool) with microsoft sql server.  From what I saw, the DataSource option is recommended (as is the case for most connection pools I've seen).  However, I was not able to form a connection correctly with the sql server database based on the examples I've seen - wondering if anyone has a working example to which I can plug my DB info into.

Comment: It was pretty useful to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure you have taken the following steps:

1. If using maven, make sure that you have the following dependency in your pom file (if using JDK7/8):

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
       <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.1</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```

   If using another build tool, change the resource URL accordingly (or just download the jar file from the maven repository if there is no other option for you).

   I believe you need the sqljdbc4.jar file in your pom file as well (I could be wrong about this requirement so I may update the post once I reconfirm)
2. Import the following in your class along with other references:

   ```
   import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
   import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
   ```
3. Add the following final properties (or simply load them from config file):

   ```
    private final String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://";
    private final String serverName= "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";   
    private final int portNumber = 1433;
    private final String databaseName= "ACTUALDBNAME";    

    private final String userName = "ACTUALUSERNAME"; 
    private final String password = "ACTUALPASSWORD";

    private final String selectMethod = "cursor";
   ```

   You can retrieve the connection URL like this:

   ```
    public String getConnectionUrl() {
         return url+this.serverName+":"+this.portNumber+";databaseName="+this.databaseName+";user="+this.userName+";password="+this.password+";selectMethod="+this.selectMethod+";";
   ```

   }

Then, the following should give you the DataSource you need in order to get a connection:

```
 public DataSource getDataSource() {
      final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(); 
      ds.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
      ds.setDataSourceClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource");
     // ds.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", this.serverName);
     //ds.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", this.databaseName);
      ds.addDataSourceProperty("url", this.getConnectionUrl());
      ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", this.userName);
      ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", this.password);
      ds.setInitializationFailFast(true);
      ds.setPoolName("wmHikariCp");
      return ds;
   }
```

or

```
public DataSource getDataSource() {
     HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
     config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
     config.setDataSourceClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource");
     config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", this.serverName);
     config.addDataSourceProperty("port", this.portNumber);
     config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", this.databaseName);
     config.addDataSourceProperty("user", this.userName);
     config.addDataSourceProperty("password", this.password);

     return new HikariDataSource(config);  //pass in HikariConfig to HikariDataSource
}
```

The preferred route is to pass the HikariConfig to the HikariDataSource constructor.  You can also load the config from a properties file.

Then get connection from the datasource:

```
Connection con = null;
con = ds.getConnection();  //where ds is the dataSource retrieved from step 5
```

Comment: thanks - it turned out I was using the wrong DataSourceClassName when testing with hikaricip - I love the fact that there are plenty of people with close votes yet only one answer - says more about these folks than it does about my question