# Unknown host exception when configuring HikariCP with MS sql driver

Tags: sql-server, hikaricp

Here is my Hikari datasource configuration:

```html
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:sqlserver://" />
    <property name="initializationFailFast" value="false"/>
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
        <property name="username" value="nexgen"/>
    <property name="password" value="nexgen"/>
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="1000"/>
        <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="USE NexGen;SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Transactions"/>
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="serverName">"DEVWORX01\DEV2014"</prop>
            <prop key="databaseName">NexGen</prop>
            <prop key="user">nexgen</prop>
            <prop key="password">nexgen</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is the stack trace:

```html
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: springHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1003ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:195)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:147)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
    at com.pevco.persist.reports.ReportsDaoImpl.setDataSource(ReportsDaoImpl.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl$BeanPropertyHandler.setValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:454)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host "DEVWORX01, named instance DEV2014" failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: "DEVWORX01". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:3589)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:972)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:314)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:171)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:436)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$500(HikariPool.java:65)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:567)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:560)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host "DEVWORX01, named instance DEV2014" failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: "DEVWORX01". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

The above line is what I have been focusing on. I've tried using just the IP address instead of the server name.

I've tried using dataSourceClassName with same result:

> ```
>   <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource" />
> ```

All with the same result. I am able to connect using a different datasource. I am also able to connect using sqlcmd.

I've looked at the many SO already existing questions and it appears my configuration should work. 
[implementing hikaricp with microsoft sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354626/implementing-hikaricp-with-microsoft-sql-server)

[How to set up datasource with Spring for HikariCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172643/how-to-set-up-datasource-with-spring-for-hikaricp)

As well as the [hikariCP documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby).

I can't see anything wrong with the setup. Why am I getting the unknown host exception? Another set of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the SQL Server with SQL Studio or with Excel or another tool? How does the connection string look then there?

Comment: Yes, I can connect with SSMS using the username and password that is used in the configuration above. I can also connect with sqlcmd using - sqlcmd -S 192.168.16.163\DEV2014 -U nexgen -P nexgen -d NexGen

Comment: If you tried with the IP address, you shouldn't be able to get an UnknownHostException.  Maybe a connection refused or other error.  What is the exception you get when you use the IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `jdbcUrl`.  Also, there are quotes around your hostname/instance, there probably shouldn't be.  You can also separate the instance from the host in the configuration as below:

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="initializationFailFast" value="false"/>
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="username" value="nexgen"/>
    <property name="password" value="nexgen"/>
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="1000"/>
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="serverName">DEVWORX01</prop>
            <prop key="instanceName">DEV2014</prop>
            <prop key="databaseName">NexGen</prop>
            <prop key="user">nexgen</prop>
            <prop key="password">nexgen</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: With the jdbcUrl I was getting a warning that it was ignoring it. So I believed the warning. Yes setting it up as listed here finally worked. TYVM!